# Saving a complex watermark on image

Tags: image, editing, watermark

I'm not sure if this is even possible.

I have an image within a div.

```
<div id="image">
  <img src="mine.jpg" />
</div>
```

And I have another div with text, that is placed on top of the image (well, more precisely, on the div that contains an image).

```
<div id="image">
  <img src="mine.jpg" />
  <div id="watermark">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Now, is it possible to save this as an image? (hm, it sounds a bit ridiculous even while I'm typing this question out!).

It sounds more like "how do I take a screenshot of user's browser".

Even if above is impossible, is there even a remotely relevant approach to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, such a thing is not possible. The best way to do this is to compose the image using serverside code. Like PHP.

I think with html5 you can make such thins with the canvas but thats far away from a everyday use, at the moment.

Comment: Any idea how I would achieve this using PHP?